# How to map foreign keys in two entities referencing each other

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-model-first

I have an error here and can't quite get the logic behind it. I am using Entity Framework 6 with a model-first approach. I have designed two tables that reference each other like this:

[image]

Basically, an account needs to be in a company while a company has to have an account as an administrator. However, I get an error from the EF validator:

> Error 3014: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 224, 249:The foreign key 'Foreign key constraint 'CompaniesAccounts1' from table CompaniesSet (Id) to table AccountsSet (Id):' is not being enforced in the model. An Association or inheritance relationship needs to be created to enforce this constraint.

`CompaniesAccounts1` is the first association (1...*) you see here, `Accounts` being the principal. The second association has `Companie`s as principal. Anybody know why I am getting this error?

All 4 properties are non-nullable `Int32` types.

Comment: From a relational standpoint, what you are trying to do here is not possible.  At least one of the properties has to be nullable.  You are creating a chicken and egg problem here.  You need a company record to attach the admin account to, but you need an account record for that account to assign as the admin account on the company record.

Comment: Ok I changed CompanyId to nullable and the second relation to * and 0..1, respectively. I still get the error. Am I still missing something?

Comment: Hmmm, weird. I inspected the designer xml file and found a few artifacts from associations that were no longer there. After deleting those, the sql file and the Model.Context.tt and Model.tt, it sorted itself out. I now got 0..1 and * on one association and * and 0...1 on the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to AgapwIesu's comment, I came up with the following solution:

[image]

Strange thing is, and I noticed because I already tried it like this and still got the error above. After digging through the xml files of the entity model, I found a few old references that I didn't use anymore. So they messed with my existing model. After deleting those and the generated files/database script and rebuilding everything, it worked.